# Saving Excel to fixed Width format - extra tabs

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a VBA macro that takes a spreadhsheet and turns it into a fixedwidth format in another sheet using the first column only.  When I save it, it always seems to have extra tabs in the text file at the end of line.

I have tried several text formats (tab, msdos, etc.), but they all put those tabs in there. There is nothing in columns b,c,d,e,f,etc.  so I am not sure why it is doing that.

Comment: Are you sure there's nothing in those columns?  After you run your macro, but before you save the outputted sheet, highlight columns B thru ??? and hit "delete" to clear them, then try and save it.  Does it still have (as many) extra tabs?  Also, have you confirmed the tabs aren't being inserted by the macro into the first column on the output sheet?

Comment: Maybe there was something in there that I couldn't see.  When I cleared everything and ran my macro, it did save without the tabs. Thanks

Comment: If you post your code in the question, maybe someone can see where the issue is coming from.